# regex, matching optional dot before \b

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of street names, and I am trying to clean street names like "St Augustine" and "St. Augustine" so I can replace them with "Saint Augustine"
I am trying to match either "St" or "St.", and I tried using the following, but it doesn't seem to match the dot. I am using python.

```
\bSt\.?\b
```

Comment: maybe you would like to share some of the relevant code, the error could originate somewhere else besides the regex itself

Answer (score 1):

`.` isn't a word character, so there isn't a word boundary after the dot. Look for the word boundary *before* the dot:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\bSt\.?\b', 'St. Augustine')
['St']
>>> re.findall(r'\bSt\b\.?', 'St. Augustine')
['St.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a optional matching group:

```
r'\bSt(\.)?\b'
```

For example, to match either `Important` or `Import`:

```
r'\Import(ant)?\'
```

Comment: That doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Python docs say:](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

> In Python’s string literals, \b is the backspace character, ASCII value 8. If you’re not using raw strings, then Python will convert the \b to a backspace, and your RE won’t match as you expect it to.

So im guessing (because the lack of information from your post) the solution to your problem would be `r'\bSt\.?\b'` (raw string, otherwise `\b` means backspace).